# Could not find any META-INF / No Persistence provider

Tags: java

Eu tenho esses erros ao tentar compilar: meu hibernate 5.4.3.Final eu criei minha pasta pasta META-INF

Como posso resolver isso?

```
INFO: HHH000318: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named market
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at util.Manager.<init>(Manager.java:19)
    at util.Manager.getInstance(Manager.java:14)
    at dao.PadraoDAO.listarTodos(PadraoDAO.java:11)
    at view.eeee.main(eeee.java:33)
```

eu criei a pasta meta inf 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

codigo do meu persistance.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.2"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <!-- Define persistence unit -->
    <persistence-unit name="market">
     <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/K21_livraria_bd"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Poderia coloca o teu código na pergunta ou no github?

Comment: @MauryDeveloper já vou editar.

Comment: Mano eu percebi uma coisa o eclipse não me deixa criar na pasta src apenas fora dela pode ser por isso?

Comment: Não sei. Qual programa você usar?

Comment: adicionei @MauryDeveloper eu uso o eclipse, e sempre que eu vou criar um folder na src ele automaticamente cria na pasta do projeto não no src.

Comment: Deve ser algum bug do eclipse.

Comment: consegui criar eu estava tentando criar source folder ...